# Privacy Policy Warning Won't Go Away

Tags: facebook, alert, privacy

We've received the following warning:

Please update your privacy policy for Brewtoad to avoid enforcement action. The URL may be missing or returning an error.
Also, be sure your privacy policy displays on your website or app. For more info, refer to Platform Policy II.3 and this external resource: http://www.applicationprivacy.org/platform-requirements/facebook/.

When we click to update the privacy policy, we're directed to this page where we're being forced to create an App Center page. We don't want that. We only use the Facebook app for users to login with Facebook.

When we go to edit our app normally, there isn't an option to "submit a privacy policy."

This message is an alert that won't go away because we've "read" it.

Previous questions about this issue have answers insinuating that all you have to do is add the privacy policy url and that the message can be marked as read and the alert will go away

Neither of those things appears to be true. Instead, it looks as though facebook is trying to muscle us into some kind of integration with App Center that we don't want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to publish your app to App Center - just add privacy policy to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/appdetails and all will be fine, trust me.

Comment: Are you replaced APP_ID with your login application id?

Comment: Right we did that. Didn't realize it at first. Either way, that's where we linked to the privacy policy, and the alert is still there. We've saved this page, but we don't want to "submit for review" to the app center.

Comment: Don't worry about alert and app center, just mark the mark as read.

Comment: Does the privacy policy URL you're using actually exist and load? (check with facebook's debug tool)

Answer (score 0):

You must provide a privacy policy in the required field on the app options page:

1. Head to https://developers.facebook.com/apps
2. Select your app
3. Click 'Edit app'
4. Click on 'App details' on the left
5. Fill the 'Privacy policy' url field with your privacy policy

If you don't have a privacy policy and need to generate one, I'm the founder of a service that does just that, and has a specific Facebook integration: [www.iubenda.com/en/facebook](http://www.iubenda.com/en/facebook)

Comment: We do have a privacy policy. It's in place exactly where it should be, but the warning alert still hasn't gone away.